# How to manage state in Gatsby Js project

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I have setup my project in Gatsby js. where in header file i have created one state for toggle button on click of button that place in header.js file. I need that button state in my page so how can i get that state from header to in my page (like in about us page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple ways of doing it, from using a context ([`useContext` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)) to the most straightforward approach (lifting up the value of the state).

Without any other implementation details, I'd choose the second one.

```
const Header = ({ sendStateToParent: {} }) => {
   const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

   const handleOnClick=()=>{
     setIsOpen(!isOpen);
     sendStateToParent(isOpen);
   }

   return <section>
      Some Header stuff
      <div onClick={handleOnClick}>I'm a hamburger menu</div>
   </section
}
```

*Note: I'm destructuring the `props`, but you can use `props.sendStateToParent` if needed.*

Basically, you are sending, through `props`, a function (`sendStateToParent`, set as an empty object to avoid code breaking if it's not received from all pages where `Header` is used but you can set it as a void function too). The `onClick` function handles the inner state (`isOpen`), toggling its value, and lifts up the current value through `sendStateToParent` (from `props`).

So, your parent component (about.js) should look like:

```
const About=()=>{
  const sendStateToParent = (isOpen) =>{
    console.log("The menu is:", isOpen)
  }

  return <Layout>
   <Header sendStateToParent={sendStateToParent} />
   <h2>Some other content </h2>
  <Layout>
}
```

In the parent component (`About`) you must define the function sent to the children component (`Header`), `sendStateToParent` which is receiving a value (`isOpen`) because the `handleOnClick` in the children component.

So in your `sendStateToParent` you have available the current state of the `isOpen`, there you can play it as you want with it (using it in a `useEffect` hook, etc).

Comment: Thank for you response @ferran but i have call header component for all pages in layout file and so how can i get state in page.

Comment: Well, it should be the opposite. From the `About` page you should call the `Layout`. If you are calling the `About` in the `Layout`, all components where you use the `Layout` will inherit the `About` structure. If you want to keep it that way, you can apply the same approach that I've used, sending again the state from the `Layout` to the `About`. Instead of receiving the `sendStateToParent` in the `About`, you will be getting it in the `Layout` but the idea is the same

Comment: OKay but what if I want to pass state from parent to child?

Comment: Then use it like any other prop... From the parent component: `<ChildComponent anyProp={anyValue}>`  in this case `anyValue` can be the value of the lifted state from any other component.